# How to place figures in Springer latex template？

Tags: floats, journal-publishing

I am preparing my manuscript for a Springer journal. I would like to place my figures as shown in the following:
[image]

My codes:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%
% For two-column wide figures use
\begin{figure*}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example.eps}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

[image]

Can someone help me ? Thank you !

Comment: Springer will take care of the layout.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Johannes_B that the journal staff will/should finalize the layout.

However, if you want to get close the the final layout e.g. to check space constraints, you could arrange your figures using a tabular environment. Here is the relevant code:

```
\begin{figure*}\sidecaption
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
\begin{tabular}{c c}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example.eps} &
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example.eps}
\end{tabular}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
```

I had to reduce the width of the figures to 0.3 to allow the sidecaption to work. Didn't play with the parameters though, so I don't know where the actual threshold is.

Comment: It is a useful idea! Many thanks! @engineer